# Keeping a Fragment that is added at runtime

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an app. that is using Fragments. The Main Activity starts with 2 Fragments. One of these Fragments contains a button that is used to add a 3'rd Fragment at runtime like this:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Activity activity = getActivity();

            if (fragment3 == null) {
                getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_content3, new ThirdFragment())
                .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
                .commit();
        }
```

The ThirdFragment class looks like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.v(getTag(), "FRAG onCreate CALLED!");
    this.setRetainInstance(true);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.third_fragment, container, false);
return view;
```

The problem is that I cannot understand how to keep this fragment's view from being removed when the Activity is recreated. I have tried to @Override the onCreate() method and use setRetainInstance(true) to no avail.

**So, my question is:**

What is the proper approach to keep a dynamically(at runtime) added Fragment from being removed when the Activity gets recreated?

Answer (score 0):

> In this situation, you can ensure that important information about the activity state is preserved by implementing an additional callback method that allows you to save information about the state of your activity: `onSaveInstanceState()`.
>
> The system calls `onSaveInstanceState()` before making the activity vulnerable to destruction. The system passes this method a Bundle in which you can save state information about the activity as name-value pairs, using methods such as putString() and putInt(). Then, if the system kills your application process and the user navigates back to your activity, the system recreates the activity and passes the Bundle to both `onCreate()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()`. Using either of these methods, you can extract your saved state from the Bundle and restore the activity state. If there is no state information to restore, then the Bundle passed to you is null (which is the case when the activity is created for the first time).[Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#SavingActivityState)

**Solution:**

So, you have only a bundle inside method `onSaveInstanceState()`to keep information about your fragment and as fragment is a complex object, you can not store it directly inside the bundle.

My suggestion is @override the `onSaveInstanceState()` and use a `boolean` flag to indicate if your third fragment should be attached(visbible). Soon, you can use the `OnCreate() or onRestoreInstanceState()` and get the bundle to read your flag and depending of it, you can create or not your fragment.